# MySQL Query Checking Multiple Records In One Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following data in php:

`ID & Timestamps` for each blog

Then I have a table which contains:

```
| id | blog | timestamp |
```

I need to find out which of my php timestamp data *does not* equal the `timestamp` in the mysql database.

Sure I could run a hundred queries for each and every timestamp I have in php to look if it is changed, but that seems inefficient.

Is there any way to put a single query in Mysql to get the data?

To clarify, my php `ID & timestamps` are in an array like

```
Array ( [3] => Array ( [timestamp] => 1389414084 ) )
```

I need to check in mysql if the record with ID=3 has the timestamp of 1389414084.

Problem is, with a lot of data to check this would end up being a huge number of queries. And I only need the ones that do not match.

I have no idea how to go about this so any help would be very appreciated.

To clarify - the first data is json. That's how it has to be. I decode it and then have to match it up to the blogs timestamp.

Comment: So take your PHP data, stuff it into a table in MySQL. Then a simple `JOIN` query will get you what you want.

Comment: It might help to put this into context a little more - WHY would you care if the timestamp in PHP does not equal that of the timestamp in the database?

Comment: @Cameron I need to know if blog has been updated in comparison to the php data I have. If timestamp is the same, it means it has not, therefore I do not need to bother with it.

Comment: @MarcB Would this be feasible for a high traffic site in your opinion. This would not be a 'once in a while' deal. Lots of users with lots of tables, I guess that's what I'm trying to say :)

Comment: the better question would be is WHY you're keeping two separate sets of data in two separate systems?  You'd be better off keeping your "last updated" data in the DB. if this data has to be kept per-user, so each person gets a customized "things updated since your last visit", that's just an extra field in this "last updated" record table.

Comment: @MarcB Well here's the problem. The first data actually IS in mysql, but it's json... and it probably has to stay that way. So I get if from mysql, decode it and I have my array.

Comment: Can you just load all of the data in your database in one query and then loop over the data in PHP to check it and print out if you come across any differences?

Comment: why would it have to stay that way? converting native<->json is trivial, and storing it as a monolithic string (even if it's json) in mysql eliminates any chance of doing what mysql is designed for - relational operations.

Comment: mysql in json? So do you have no control over the data you are getting via json?

Comment: @Cameron - That could work nicely  but how would I get the data in the first place. Let's say I have 100 ids - how do I make a multiple query to get 100 ids?... Without doing 100 queries. Thanks

Comment: @Cameron - I'm getting the json string and I can change that string. That's about all the control I can have.

Comment: @NoodleHead just go `SELECT id, timestamp FROM blog_posts` - what are you using to query the database? Can you even run your own queries?

Comment: @Cameron - Mysqli->prepared statements - Yes, but how do I select ONLY the ids I want, instead of the whole table which has thousands of them? I need to query 100 specific ids from thousands etc... Or are you saying to get all thousands of them and then loop over them in php?

Comment: @NoodleHead Well it is probably faster to make only one MYSQL query like the one I mentioned and just iterate over it using PHP to find the ones that you want. I am not sure you have any other option.

Comment: @Cameron I can parse it once I get it out of mysql and decode it. But it seems overkill to do 100 targeted mysql queries or get 10000 records just to check for 100 in php. Or maybe I'm not thinking right about this.

Comment: @NoodleHead It really depends on how often you are having to run this query of yours as to whether or not it matters. Running 100 queries on every page load would be overkill, yes. But running it once a month, no.

Comment: This would be a client query - with a lot of clients. So it would not be something happening once in a while, but very very frequently.

Comment: @NoodleHead ah ok. Is the database you are querying external to your system? Are you maintaining a list of external blog_posts?

Comment: @Cameron - Yes. I guess this whole problem would easily be solved if I could create a query like SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id = 1,3,4,294,748 etc... :)

Comment: OMG it was so damm simple "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(1, 4,99, 249)"

Comment: @NoodleHead well you COULD do that, though I don't know if there is an upper limit on chaining AND's in your WHERE clause like `AND id = 3 AND id = 4`.

I would suggest putting whatever code you come up with into a script and update your database every hour or so with cron. That way you are not having to repeat the query for every client every time they request it.

Comment: @NoodleHead Oh right! I totally forgot about that syntax. Nice. I would still look at running an update script with cron rather than just running that code on demand.

Comment: @Cameron I knew there had to be catch - I can have more than 30 records here so I can't have something that cuts me off after a certain number.

Comment: @NoodleHead does the IN() syntax limit you to 30?

Comment: It added it automatically inside phpmyadmin mysql query window. I put it in without the 30 limit - it came back WITH it

Comment: @NoodleHead well that might not be a problem when you are running the query with PHP. If it does limit you to 30 for whatever reason, then you can just construct your query by looping over your array of posts and appending the IDs to your query.

Comment: That might actually work - I'll try it like that and see. Thanks

Comment: Just one problem: how exactly do I create a prepared statement with so many values?

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is make hash of ID, Blog & Timestamp and store it in the table itself. And instead of checking id & timestamp, you may check for the hash match (select * from my BlogTimeStamp where hash NOT IN ('hash1', 'hash2', ....).

I don't know your exact requirement. maybe there would be a better solution altogether

Comment: I tried something similar but it seems there's a limit to chaining multiple records - I get an automated LIMIT 0 , 30 tagged on.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt quite get where you are getting the LIMIT added. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myBlogTable
WHERE timestamp NOT IN (1389414084);
```

If you use a select statement to get the `1389414084` then insert that in the parentheses instead of hard coding in the timestamp so that the query is dynamic if you ever need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in the end. I just broke down the query and constructed it so that I had everything in one query.

```
SELECT * FROM title WHERE id IN((SELECT id FROM title WHERE id = '75' AND date ='1392501995'),(SELECT id FROM title WHERE id = '74' AND date ='1392401481'))
```

So you just create it in php.

```
$i = count($fav);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM title WHERE id IN(';
    foreach($fav as $key => $val){
        $sql .= "(SELECT id FROM title WHERE id = '".$key."' AND date ='".$val["date"]."')"; 
        if($i > 1) {
            $sql .= ",";
            }
        $i = $i-1;
    }
    $sql .= ")";
```